# How to create a CNAME for an elastic beanstalk container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, devops, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cname

I have an external domain provider and I have the following subdomain: ltstest.test.com. I have created an hosted zone for it using Route53 service from AWS. Now when I'm trying to create a CNAME for my elastic beanstalk environment an error occurs:

> RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name ltstest.test.com. is not permitted at apex in zone ltstest.test.com.

Anyone had same issue and solved it? Thanx in advance!

Comment: You can't have CNAME for the Apex domain and in your case it is ltstest.test.com (delegation) , you may want to create an alias record instead in Route53.

Comment: I tried also to create an A record but after I have created it with an alias to the my ebs environment I didn't find the ip that should be created.

Comment: With A-Alias record, you just need to map the ebs name , no need to worry about IP address.

Comment: Ok but how do I set to my subdomain the A-Alias then or how do I link my subdomain to the ebs after A-Alias is created?